# How can I display a GIFV file in an Android app?

Tags: android, animated-gif, imgur

I cannot believe how difficult this is.  I'm making a fairly simple app and using data from Reddit's AWW subreddit.  A good portion of the posts are in the GIFV format, and I cannot seem to find ANY way to display these files in an Android view.  I've experimented with Picasso, Fresco, Glide...none work.

Can someone tell me what magic is required or what incantation to use?

Comment: What about an embedded web view? Seems like the easiest solution to me.

Comment: I messed around a bit with a webview, but couldn't figure out how to load just the image without all the browser ui.  imgur seems to want to load it's header and other things that mess up the view.  It's not a pretty solution

Answer (score 2):

If you are pulling from Reddit, you will notice that a lot of content comes from Imgur. In the Imgur page that is loaded, the gifv file is actually presented as an MP4 embedded in the page.

For imgur:

Option one, display the whole url embedded in a Webview. This is a very painful method, as there are a lot of configuration options which need to be set to get this working nicely, or to achieve scaling. In addition there is a lot of unrequired overhead in order to parse the webpage, and run the javascript and other web elements on the page.

Option two, use the Imgur API to retrieve the image. (I have not tried this)

Option three, Imgur Gifv files use an mp4 video file to display their content. For a given Imgur gifv url, if you inspect the page source, find the mp4 source url and display that in exoplayer. (For example [http://i.imgur.com/1t9KQjg.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/1t9KQjg.gifv) uses [http://i.imgur.com/1t9KQjg.mp4](https://i.imgur.com/1t9KQjg.mp4)).

XML

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView android:id="@+id/my_player"
                                                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Java:

```
mPlayerView =  mCardView.findViewById(R.id.my_player);

mPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
              new DefaultRenderersFactory(browserActivity),
              new DefaultTrackSelector(),
              new DefaultLoadControl());
mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
mPlayer.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);

mPlayerView.setPlayer(mPlayer);


Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://i.imgur.com/1t9KQjg.mp4');

DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(browserActivity, Util.getUserAgent(browserActivity, "Obelisk"), null);
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

mPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Glide to load the gifs even videos.

Can be used as:

```
GlideApp.with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

GitHub:[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Hmmm, I tried Glide but not GlideApp.  Can you confirm that you've tried an actual GIFV file?  GlideApp seems to have a lot more requirements than Glide, but I'll give it a shot.